# Possible to Change Rails Routing Convention?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm wondering if it's possible to edit the default Rails routing convention to fetch a specific record based on a field that is not the ID?

For instance, instead of retrieving a specific record based on ID, with the verb/url combination:

GET /users/:id

Retrieve a specific record based on username, with the verb/url combination:

GET /users/:username

I don't see why this would be a problem theoretically, as long as usernames were required to be unique, but I'm having trouble understanding how to implement it based on the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

I have gathered that I will need to add a line to my `routes.rb` file, to define a singular resource, just prior to:

```
resources :users
```

However, I'm having trouble understanding the syntax to accomplish this. Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible and they are called [Non Restful Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) in the rails documentation

A trivial example is doing the below in your `routes.rb`

`get ':users/:show/:username', controller: "users", action: "show"`

and in your `UsersController` you have a show action that looks like this:

```
def show  
  if params[:id].present?
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  elsif params[:username].present?
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
  end
end
```

This way you support showing by `id` and `username`, if you want do disable support for either of them, modify the `if` clause as you wish

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, perfect, thanks so much for your help! This also clarifies a few other similar, but slightly different, situations that I should be able to handle in approximately the same way.

Comment: @badgercore fill my basket with an upvote by clicking the up arrow beside the answer

Comment: @bjhaid I can't upvote yet, due to reputation being below 15. Trying to up it now to get you the deserved upvote!

Comment: @bjhaid This is working to enforce the old GET by ID, i.e. /users/1, but when I try to access directly by a username, i.e. users/username, it errors out. Logs show ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound <Couldn't find User with id=username>;  So it doesn't appear to be hitting the elseif statement in the show method. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: @bjhaid Tried to force this, since I don't really need to retain the ability to get by ID. So, I removed the if and elseif statements and just left the line: `@user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])` in the show method. However, I'm still receiving the same error message about not finding a record with id=username.

Comment: @badgercore can you post what you have in your logs, you can add this to the file line of your `show` action `Rails.logger.info params`

Answer (score 0):

The routes does not care if it is an ID or username.
It is really how you find it in the controller.

Just in the user show controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_username params[:id]
end
```

Comment: I'm receiving the following error when trying to use this method: No MethodError <undefined method `find_by_name` for #<Class....

Comment: oh, it should be find_by_username. I'll change it. Assuming there is a   attribute called username in your user model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to change the to_param method like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{id} #{name}".parameterize
  end
end
```

This would give the url as: /user/id-name.  If you want to get rid of the id before the name it gets a little more complicated.  If you were just to remove it, it will more than likely break since ActiveRecord needs the id first for finds.

To get around this I would suggest using FriendlyId gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

There is also a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast) showing how to use Friendly_id but its pretty straight forward.